# Why "SELECT ... WHERE id=1=0" returns all rows except one with id=1?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=1=0
```

returns all rows from `myTable` except one which has `id=1`?

`myTable` content:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | dog   |
| 2  | cat   |
| 3  | parrot|
+----+-------+
```

Now run: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=1=0`

Output:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 2  | cat   |
| 3  | parrot|
+----+-------+
```

Comment: Evaluates as `WHERE (id = 1) = 0`... When ID = 1 it ends up as 1 which <> 0.

Comment: ... and in MySQL `0` equals `false`. `id = 1` is an expression that results in a boolean value (true, false or null), so MySQL expects a boolean on the right side of `= `. It finds `0`, which it interprets as `false`.

Comment: @jarlh I have used your logic as answer. As you didn't posted as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that the logic should be being evaluated as:

```
WHERE (id = 1) = 0
```

This is equivalent to:

```
WHERE (id = 1) "is false"
```

Or:

```
WHERE id <> 1
```

Try running these examples:

```
select 1=1=0, 1=2=3, 1=1=0
```

Answer (score 8):

Default operator precedence works as follows :

```
WHERE (ID=1)=0
```

Which resutls false in case of `id=1`